# get value of material-option angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, web, angular-material

New to Angular, I'm trying use Angular Material dropdown menu. I want it to display the months but when the user clicks on it I want to get the month's number so I may use it as a URL parameter.

My actual HTML code:

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 250px;">
     <mat-select placeholder="Sélectionnez un mois" #list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" name="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let month of months" (mat-option)="onUpdate($event)" [value]="month.viewValue" >
            {{ month.viewValue }}
     </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In my component:

```
protected months = [
    {value: '0', viewValue: 'Janvier'},
    {value: '1', viewValue: 'Février'},
    {value: '2', viewValue: 'Mars'},
    {value: '3', viewValue: 'Avril'},
    {value: '4', viewValue: 'Mai'},
    {value: '5', viewValue: 'Juin'},
    {value: '6', viewValue: 'Juillet'},
    {value: '7', viewValue: 'Août'},
    {value: '8', viewValue: 'Septembre'},
    {value: '9', viewValue: 'Octobre'},
    {value: '10', viewValue: 'Novembre'},
    {value: '11', viewValue: 'Décembre'}
];
onNgModelChange(event: Event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

I can get the `viewValue` when I click on the select, but I'm not succeeding at getting the `value` parameter (the number). How may I manage to get it?

I want for example to get the number "1" when the user clicks on "Février".

Answer (score 2):

```
 <mat-option *ngFor="let month of months" (mat-option)="onUpdate($event)" [value]="month.value" >
        {{ month.viewValue }}
 </mat-option>
```

here is the typo you put `month.viewValue` as value for your options, so you'll never get the  `value` you want. I hope it helped

Comment: Thanks ! So I changed this `[value]="month.viewValue"` to this `[value]="month.value"` and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

In your `mat-select`

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedOptions"
(change) = "getValue()"
```

this particular (ngModel) piece of code is doing a two-way binding. Add a (change) event in your `mat-select` instead of `ngModelChange`

So in your comoponent.ts you can get it

```
selectedOptions: String = "0";

protected months = [
 {value: '0', viewValue: 'Janvier'},
 {value: '1', viewValue: 'Février'},
 {value: '2', viewValue: 'Mars'},
 {value: '3', viewValue: 'Avril'},
 {value: '4', viewValue: 'Mai'},
 {value: '5', viewValue: 'Juin'},
 {value: '6', viewValue: 'Juillet'},
 {value: '7', viewValue: 'Août'},
 {value: '8', viewValue: 'Septembre'},
 {value: '9', viewValue: 'Octobre'},
 {value: '10', viewValue: 'Novembre'},
 {value: '11', viewValue: 'Décembre'}
];

getValue() {
    console.log(selectedOptions); // will log the selected value
}
```